What does Chernoff bound want to point out? Intuition
e.g. Chebyshev's bound $P(|x-\mu| \geq a) \leqslant \frac{\sigma^2}{a^2}$ tells us the upper-bound probability that $X$ deviates from its mean (in absolute value) by more than a certain amount.
I can't figure out what Chernoff's bound $\mathrm{P}(X \geq a) \leq \inf _{t>0} M(t) e^{-t a}$ is pointing out. Why did Chernoff (actually Herman Rubin) one day decide to plug the $MGF$ (rather than e.g. $e^X$) into Markov's inequality?? What is this inequality telling us? How would you explain this inequality to a kid!?
I have no prior knowledge about Fourier & Laplace transforms

Herman Chernoff did not invent Chernoff's bound; Herman Rubin did.  Chernoff did describe it.  Though Harald Cramér had done something similar more than a decade earlier.

Having $t>0$ allows optimising the RHS, i.e. making it as small as possible. On the other hand, requiring MGF to exist is much stronger than just the variance need by Chebyshev.

@vanderWolf ty very much. Yes, the MGF gotta be finite. But from your comment I don't understand why involving MGF (rather than variance alone) in Markov's inequality, results in better tail bound. In addition, your comment doesn't answer my original questions.

Let $m = E[X]$. Once you have Markov's inequality, you immediately have $$P(|X-m|^k \geq t) \leq \inf_k \frac{E|X-m|^k}{t^k}\,\quad(1)\,.$$ From here, it is only natural to consider $$P(X-m\geq t) \leq \inf_{\lambda>0} \frac{E[e^{\lambda (X-m)}]}{e^{\lambda t}}\,\quad (2)\,.$$
It is not true that the above exponential bound always outperforms a second moment bound. For example, consider $X_i \overset{\text{i.i.d.}}{\sim}\mathrm{Bern}(p)$. You can check that for every $q \leq p$, one has $$P(X_1+\dots+X_n \leq qn) \leq \exp(-n H(q\|p))\,,$$ where $H(q\|p)$ is the Kullback-Leibler divergence between a $\mathrm{Bern}(q)$ and a $\mathrm{Bern}(p)$. In fact, by Sanov's or Cramér's Theorem, for any closed $B\subset \mathbb R$, one has $$P(n^{-1}(X_1+\dots+X_n)\in B) \leq \exp(-nI(B))\,,\quad I(B) = \inf_{q\in B}H(q\|p)\,.$$ Play around with different values to see what the second moment bound has to say about the above tail probability.
Some things to think about:

If $P(|X|\geq t) \leq 2e^{t^2\sigma^2/2}$ for some $\sigma^2>0$ and every $t\geq 0$, what can be said about $E[X]$? What can be said about $\mathrm{Var}[X]$?
What is the relationship between the bounds (1) and (2)?

As an aside, it is unfortunate that such estimates are referred to as Chernoff bounds in statistics when the idea was already known at least as early as Esscher or Cramér.
